# Set postgres column to not null with default without update

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl, alter-table

Is there a way to add a `not null` constraint to a column and replace all existing null values with a default in one statement?

```
alter table t
alter column c set default 0,
alter column c set not null;
```

Doesn't seem to work, gives an error:

> ```
> column "c" contains null values
> ```

Comment: What's wrong with multiple statements?

Comment: Environment specific issue where there are only permissions to modify the schema, not the data.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, yes. Pretty simple, too:

```sql
ALTER TABLE t
  ALTER COLUMN c TYPE int USING (COALESCE(c, 0))
, ALTER COLUMN c SET DEFAULT 0
, ALTER COLUMN c SET NOT NULL;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6e352ce2be60bdd2083dd001dd9386b7)*

You just have to think around a corner. We change the type from `int` to `int`, so no actual change. But it allows us to slip in the [`USING` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) that does the magic.

Comment: And it's even faster than using a separate `UPDATE` statement. Just measured `USING` approach is 6 times faster than `UPDATE+ALTER` on 8M rows (no index on changed field)

Comment: ⚠️This approach **locks the whole table** until it finished. If you can, better use slower `UPDATE`, but without a lock.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
alter table t
alter column a type int using coalesce(a, 567),
alter column a set not null;
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6FgYsxTUsYLGZbzG5zFnS4/0).