# Query for key in an element of a JSON array

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, knex.js, jsonb

I assumed to have a `jsonb` column `header_format` in my PostgreSQL table (which turns out to be type `json[]`, really) .

[image]

A column value looks like this:

```
{"{\"label\":\"SUPPLIER\",\"name\":\"supplier_name\",\"value\":\"VNS LTD\",\"show\":true,\"showPrint\":true,\"map\":\"\",\"input_type\":\"text\",\"mapFrom\":\"header\",\"default\":true,\"note\":\"\"}","{\"label\":\"PRODUCT NAME\",\"name\":\"product_name\",\"value\":\"\",\"show\":true,\"showPrint\":true,\"input_type\":\"text\",\"map\":\"\",\"mapFrom\":\"header\",\"default\":true,\"note\":\"\"}","{\"label\":\"INVOICE / DC #\",\"name\":\"invoice_no\",\"value\":\"cs/12/1222\",\"show\":true,\"showPrint\":true,\"input_type\":\"text\",\"map\":\"\",\"mapFrom\":\"header\",\"default\":true,\"note\":\"\"}","{\"label\":\"INVOICE / DC DATE\",\"name\":\"invoice_date\",\"value\":\"2022-06-02\",\"show\":true,\"showPrint\":true,\"input_type\":\"text\",\"map\":\"DATE_EXT\",\"mapFrom\":\"header\",\"default\":true,\"note\":\"\"}","{\"label\":\"INVOICE QTY\",\"name\":\"invoice_qty\",\"value\":260,\"show\":true,\"showPrint\":true,\"input_type\":\"number\",\"map\":\"invoiceQty\",\"mapFrom\":\"header\",\"default\":true,\"note\":\"No Need to Map\"}","{\"label\":\"IR #\",\"name\":\"ir\",\"value\":\"FY-23-09-1\",\"show\":true,\"showPrint\":true,\"input_type\":\"text\",\"map\":\"\",\"mapFrom\":\"header\",\"default\":true,\"note\":\"\"}","{\"label\":\"GRN NO\",\"name\":\"grn_no\",\"value\":\"5032344565\",\"show\":true,\"showPrint\":true,\"input_type\":\"text\",\"map\":\"\",\"mapFrom\":\"header\",\"default\":true,\"note\":\"\"}","{\"label\":\"GRN DATE\",\"name\":\"grn_date\",\"value\":\"2022-06-02\",\"show\":true,\"showPrint\":true,\"input_type\":\"text\",\"map\":\"LAST_GR_DATE_EXT\",\"mapFrom\":\"header\",\"default\":true,\"note\":\"\"}","{\"label\":\"R/M CODE\",\"name\":\"rmcode\",\"value\":\"CR11803C00MAN\",\"show\":true,\"showPrint\":true,\"input_type\":\"text\",\"map\":\"\",\"mapFrom\":\"header\",\"default\":true,\"note\":\"\"}","{\"label\":\"EDS /Q /P #\",\"name\":\"eds\",\"value\":\"DE / EDS / 454\",\"show\":true,\"showPrint\":true,\"input_type\":\"text\",\"map\":\"eds\",\"mapFrom\":\"product\",\"default\":true,\"note\":\"\"}","{\"label\":\"DATE\",\"name\":\"date\",\"value\":\"2022-09-13\",\"show\":true,\"showPrint\":true,\"input_type\":\"date\",\"map\":\"\",\"mapFrom\":\"header\",\"default\":true,\"note\":\"\"}","{\"label\":\"R/M\",\"name\":\"rm\",\"value\":\"DC01+LC-MA-RL\",\"show\":true,\"showPrint\":true,\"input_type\":\"text\",\"map\":\"rm\",\"mapFrom\":\"product\",\"default\":true,\"note\":\"\"}","{\"label\":\"RECEIVED QTY\",\"name\":\"received_qty\",\"value\":260,\"show\":true,\"showPrint\":true,\"input_type\":\"number\",\"map\":\"invoiceQty\",\"mapFrom\":\"header\",\"default\":true,\"note\":\"No Need to Map\"}","{\"label\":\"SHELF LIFE\",\"name\":\"shelf_life\",\"value\":\"20.11.2022\",\"show\":true,\"showPrint\":true,\"input_type\":\"text\",\"map\":\"Shelf Life\",\"mapFrom\":\"header\",\"default\":true,\"note\":\"No Need to Map\"}","{\"label\":\"MATERIAL TEXT\",\"name\":\"material_text\",\"value\":\"CP7B-DC01,1.18 x 31.5\",\"show\":true,\"showPrint\":true,\"input_type\":\"text\",\"map\":\"MATTEXT\",\"mapFrom\":\"header\",\"default\":true,\"note\":\"\"}"}
```

I am inserting format in `header_format` column:

```
[{
label:'1',
value:'abc',
other...
},
{
label:'2',
value:'aab',
other...
}]
```

I want a list of rows when it matches `"{label:'supplier'}"` in array datatype.

I tried the following methods:

Method 1:

```
Database.rawQuery('select * from qasformones  where header_format @> "{label:supplier}"')
```

Method 2:

```
Database.rawQuery('select * from qasformones  where header_format @> "[{label:supplier}]"')
```

I got the following error:

> column "{label:supplier}" does not exist
>
> select * from qasformones where header_format @> "{label:supplier}" - column "{show:true}" does not exist

How to do this query?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you trying to use an array of values in your where clause? Then you can use the "in" keyword. But the question is a bit unclear.

Comment: @JurgenRutten I am using array data type, I want to list out all the data when it match  {label:"supplier"} in my array data type . (eg : where  label=supplier) but i never used before array data type.

Comment: Can you provide example data?

Comment: attached ,now you can see

Comment: check https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-TABLE (see:  jsonb ? text → boolean & jsonb ? text[] → boolean) these can be used to filter the results

Comment: I Tried,missing  something.

Comment: Clarify. Sorry these types of queries are new to me too. I'll experiment tomorrow.

Comment: a) don't use `json[]`, use `jsonb` and store a json array (instead of a postgres array of json values) and b) use apostrophes (`'`) to delimit literal values, not quotes (`"`).

Comment: I think both json and jsonb are same,jsonb removes whitespace but not in json.my case can't do json to jsonb because of data already having in database.

Comment: Your question would attract more answers with a fiddle. Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/5lW4OAWU Always declare your version of Postgres and disclose the actual table definition in text form. Don't post images for text data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query works for your current table design with an array of JSON values  (`json[]`):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   qasformones q
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM unnest(q.header_format) js
   WHERE  js->>'label' = 'SUPPLIER'   -- match case!
   );
```

But `json[]` is typically not what you want. Storage is inefficient, and this query is expensive and does not scale well. Consider transforming the column to `jsonb` *containing* an array or objects.

#### Fast path to sanity

`ALTER TABLE` is the fastest way - if you can afford to lock the table exclusively. See:

- [Set postgres column to not null with default without update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70994637/set-postgres-column-to-not-null-with-default-without-update/70994866#70994866)

But it does not allow subquery expressions in the `USING` clause. So wrap the functionality in a quick temporary function. (Dropped automatically at the end of your session.)

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION pg_temp.jsb_transform (json[])
  RETURNS jsonb
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT jsonb_agg(js) FROM unnest($1) js;
$func$;

ALTER TABLE qasformones
   ALTER COLUMN header_format TYPE jsonb USING pg_temp.jsb_transform(header_format);
```

Then I suggest:

```
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE qasformones;
```

And create an index:

```
CREATE INDEX qasformones_header_format_gin_idx ON qasformones USING gin (header_format jsonb_path_ops);
```

About that:

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)
- [jsonb query with nested objects in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108179/jsonb-query-with-nested-objects-in-an-array/29114520#29114520)

Now your query can be:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   qasformones q
WHERE  header_format @> '[{"label":"SUPPLIER"}]';
```

Or, using SQL/JSON path expression in Postgres 12+

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   qasformones q
WHERE  header_format @? '$ ? (@.label == "SUPPLIER")';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5lW4OAWU)

#### Regular table columns?

Your content looks highly regular. It may be more efficient, yet, to break out keys into dedicated regular table columns using [`jsonb_populate_recordset()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) See:

- [What's the proper index for querying structures in arrays in Postgres jsonb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499266/whats-the-proper-index-for-querying-structures-in-arrays-in-postgres-jsonb/27708358#27708358)
- [How to convert PostgreSQL 9.4's jsonb type to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826385/how-to-convert-postgresql-9-4s-jsonb-type-to-float/25002347#25002347)

That would result in N rows for N array elements in your current `json[]`. Probably a one-to-many design. Related:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)
- [How to perform update operations on columns of type JSONB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703476/how-to-perform-update-operations-on-columns-of-type-jsonb-/26704636#26704636)

Comment: wow,it solved my problem within seconds thanks lot @Erwin Brandstetter

Comment: How to know index created or not?

Comment: @ßãlãjî: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55448707/939860 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089729/939860

Comment: getting error while insert invalid input type for json my input looks []

Comment: returning "id" - invalid input syntax for type json

Comment: Found Jsonb  "[ ]"